# Directly compare Two 8 Bit (1 Byte) values in C++

Tags: c++, comparison, byte, bit

I'm wondering, is there a way to compare 8 bit/1 byte values similarly to the way that we could compare an int?

For example:

```
// Start with these as false
bool int_comp = false;
bool byte_comp = false;

// Set the ints
int a_int = 128;
int b_int = 128;

// Set the bytes
char a_byte = 0xC0; // 11000000
char b_byte = 0xC0; // 11000000

// This comparison works
if (a_int == b_int)
   int_comp = true;

// This comparison does not work, however
if (a_byte == b_byte)
   byte_comp = true;
```

In this case the byte comparison does not work.. Is there a way to compare bytes in a way similar to how we compare integers?

---

Edit: As it turns out this does work- thank you for the replies. I was doing something extra in my code that I did not capture here that was causing the issues. Essentially I was using a static_cast and thought that it would work but it did not.

Here is what I was doing:

```
// Start with these as false
bool int_comp = false;
bool byte_comp = false;

// Set the ints
int a_int = 128;
int b_int = 128;

// Set the bytes
int8_t a_byte = 0xC0; // 11000000
char b_byte = 0xC0; // 11000000

// This comparison works
if (a_int == b_int)
   int_comp = true;

// This comparison does not work, however
//
// Turns out that using static_cast here did not do what I thought it would do,
// even though printing out the bits using std::bitset showed that the bits
// of the casted value were the same.
//
if (a_byte == static_cast<int8_t>(b_byte))
   byte_comp = true;
```

Comment: Create a [mcve] What is `octet`?

Comment: Just changed it to DDS_Octet. It's just a generic type with 8 bits. I could put a char there instead

Comment: Do implementation with an operator. And please not that it is easier to use ```char``` than ```octet```

Comment: How is its `operator==` defined?

Comment: @Walklikeapenguin `Just changed it to DDS_Octet` OK... How is `DDS_Octet` defined then?

Comment: It's a generic 8 bit type used by DDS to send data.

I just changed it to 'char' to remove confusion

Comment: `// This comparison does not work, however if (a_byte == b_byte) byte_comp = true;` Works fine for `char`

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does it compile? If not, please show the exact error message.

Comment: Turns out I was trying to compare values of the same type but one was static casted whereas the other was just normally defined. The printed out bits with each were the same (using bitset) so I didn't think anything of it.. Guess there is more to it then that. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering, is there a way to compare **8 bit** values similarly to the way that we could compare an int?

Yes, there is. Example:

```
std::uint8_t a_octet = 0xC0; // 11000000
std::uint8_t b_octet = 0xC0; // 11000000
if (a_octet == b_octet)
```

> ... is there a way to compare **1 byte** values ...

Yes, there is. Example:

```
unsigned char a_byte = 0xC0; // 11000000
unsigned char b_byte = 0xC0; // 11000000
if (a_byte == b_byte)
```

---

> ```
> char a_byte = 0xC0; // 11000000
> ```

This doesn't work like you would expect on systems where the size of byte is 8 bits and `char` is a signed type because in such case 0xC0 is outside of representable values. The largest representable value would be 0x7f.

Otherwise your example works.

Comment: Thank you, it does work. I had tried the approach of unit8_t and char to no avail.

Turns out my issue was trying to cast values. I was trying to compare static_cast<uint8_t>data with a unit8_t defined at the top of the function. (data is a char).

Looks like static_cast didn't do what I thought it would do.